Azure: Multiple SQL users linked to single managed identity
In Azure, is it possible to link 2 separate Azure SQL database user accounts to a single managed identity?
I am connecting to an Azure SQL Database from an Azure App Service using a managed identity. Even though it's just 1 application, I want to use a SQL account with less privileges for a specific part of the application.
To create the SQL user linked to a manage identity, you issue a statement such as this:
CREATE USER [identity-name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

But an Azure App Service only have 1 managed identity, so I cannot create 2 user accounts for it.
Is there some workaround to this?

No, the user account in SQL is tied to the specific Azure identity, so you cannot have two. You can create two user assigned managed identities and have your application select the appropriate one to use.
